# Окончание глаголов с числительными

Tags: глаголы

Какое окончание глагола надо использовать с числительными, если числительное указывает количество чего-то/кого-то?
Пример: В создании документ `участвовало` или `участвовали` четырнадцать юристов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На Ваше усмотрение. Я бы написала: "В создании документа участвовали четырнадцать юристов".

[**Единственное и множественное число сказуемого**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/64-bolshinstvo)

...Согласование сказуемого с числительными

> Имя числительное, в отличие от других имен (существительного и
> прилагательного), лишено признаков числа. Иными словами, если
> существительные могут иметь формы единственного и множественного числа
> (книга – книги), то числительные не имеют таких форм (ср.: два,
> пятеро, сто пятьдесят). По этой причине с числительным собственно
> «согласование» сказуемого по форме числа принципиально невозможно.
> Форма сказуемого единственного или множественного числа выбирается
> говорящим произвольно. При постановке сказуемого в ед. ч. прошедшего
> времени сказуемое принимает форму среднего рода: пятьдесят человек
> пришло на лекцию, в ДТП погибло два человека; открылось десять новых
> магазинов и т. п.
>
> Хотя форма сказуемого не регламентируется жестко, существует ряд
> факторов, способствующих употреблению формы единственного или
> множественного числа.
>
> На постановку сказуемого в форму единственного числа влияет стремление
> автора текста обратить внимание читателей на пассивность подлежащего,
> совместность действия действующих лиц, а также на количество,
> названное в подлежащем. Пассивность подлежащего может подчеркиваться
> употреблением в качестве сказуемых глаголов со значением бытия,
> наличия: быть существовать, иметься и др.
>
> В результате урагана упало двадцать деревьев. На лекцию пришло именно
> пятьдесят человек, а не пятьдесят два. У существительного имеется
> двенадцать падежных форм.
>
> Факторы, способствующие употреблению формы множественного числа
> сказуемого, противоположны: значение раздельности действия,  акцент на
> активности лиц, названных в подлежащем, стремление автора обратить
> внимание на действие (характеристику), а не на количество.
>
> Восемь студентов уже защитили дипломные работы. Сто аспирантов пишут
> диссертации (т. е. каждый пишет собственную работу).
>
> Кроме этого следует запомнить, что:
>
> - Числительные, оканчивающиеся на один, обычно требуют формы единственного числа сказуемого: В институт поступил пятьдесят один
>   абитуриент. Но: Пятьдесят один участник обсудили проблему на круглом
>   столе (глагол обсудить означает совместное действие и не может быть
>   употреблен в форме ед. ч.).
> - Форма множественного числа сказуемого используется, если подлежащее конкретизируется определением в форме множественного числа, например
>   словами все, эти, данные, любые и др. Все пятьдесят восемь
>   абитуриентов поступили в институт. Васины пятьдесят рублей были
>   немедленно потрачены. Эти двое явились с опозданием, остальные пятеро
>   прибыли вовремя.